# Speed up reading excel file using PowerShell in hash table

Tags: excel, powershell, hashtable

Excel file has 100 k lines and 25 columns. I am reading first column then taking 2nd and 12th column value and putting them in hash table. Currently takes hours to finish.

```
# Open an Excel workbook first:
$ExcelObj = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$ExcelWorkBook = $ExcelObj.Workbooks.Open("C:\anil\VM_Data_1228_2022.xlsx")
$ExcelWorkSheet = $ExcelWorkBook.Sheets.Item("VMAudit")
# Get the number of filled in rows in the XLSX worksheet
$rowcount=$ExcelWorkSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
# Loop through all rows in Column 1 starting from Row 2 (these cells contain the VMnames)
$report = @{}
$outFile = "vm_info.csv"
"VM Name,Vcenter,Disk usage" | Out-File -FilePath $outFile
for($i=2;$i -le $rowcount;$i++){

$vmname = $ExcelWorkSheet.Columns.Item(1).Rows.Item($i).Text
if ( $vmname -inotin $report.keys){
                        $report[$vmname] = @{}
                        $report[$vmname]['vcenter'] = $ExcelWorkSheet.Columns.Item(2).Rows.Item($i).Text
                        $report[$vmname]['datasize'] = $ExcelWorkSheet.Columns.Item(12).Rows.Item($i).Text

                                    }
}

$ExcelWorkBook.close($true) 
        $report.GetEnumerator()|foreach {

        "$($_.name),$($_.value.vcenter),$($_.value.datasize)" | Out-File -FilePath $outFile -Append
                                        }
```

Tried below code its failing

```
$data = $ExcelWorksheet.Range("A1:Z100000").Value2
for( $row = $data.GetLowerBound(0); $row -lt $data.GetUpperBound(0); $row++) { 
                         #write-host $data[$row, 1] 
                         $vmname = $data[$row, 1]
                         
                         if ( $vmname -inotin $report.keys){
                        $report[$vmname] = @{}
                        $report[$vmname]['vcenter'] = $data[$row, 5]
                        $report[$vmname]['datasize'] = $data[$row, 12]
                                                           }
```

getting below message

Index operation failed; the array index evaluated to null.
At C:\anil\scripts\get_vm_disk_usage_from_excel.ps1:20 char:25

- ```
                      $report[$vmname] = @{}
  ```
- ```
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArrayIndex

Index operation failed; the array index evaluated to null.
At C:\anil\scripts\get_vm_disk_usage_from_excel.ps1:21 char:25

- ```
                      $report[$vmname]['vcenter'] = $data[$row, 5]
  ```
- ```
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArrayIndex

Index operation failed; the array index evaluated to null.
At C:\anil\scripts\get_vm_disk_usage_from_excel.ps1:22 char:25

- ...                        $report[$vmname]['datasize'] = $data[$row, 12]
- ```
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArrayIndex

Index operation failed; the array index evaluated to null.
At C:\anil\scripts\get_vm_disk_usage_from_excel.ps1:20 char:25

- ```
                      $report[$vmname] = @{}
  ```
- ```
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArrayIndex

Index operation failed; the array index evaluated to null.
At C:\anil\scripts\get_vm_disk_usage_from_excel.ps1:21 char:25

- ```
                      $report[$vmname]['vcenter'] = $data[$row, 5]
  ```
- ```
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArrayIndex

    ```
                       }
    ```

Comment: You may take a look at the great module from Doug Finke [ImportExcel](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel). That could make your life much easier.  ;-)  ... here you can see how it's used: [ImportExcel PowerShell + Excel = Better Together! with Doug Finke](https://youtu.be/0bR-8b6OMTk)

Comment: Reading cell values one at a time through interop / com is very slow. It's a whole lot faster to read an entire range into a PowerShell array and then process that - e.g. ```$data = $ExcelWorksheet.Range("A1:Z100000").Value2; for( $row = $data.GetLowerBound(0); $row -lt $data.GetUpperBound(0); $row++) { write-host $data[$row, 1] }```

Comment: Hi Mclayton, in your code how can i tell start from second row ?

Comment: You can import a complete sheet at once with the module `ImportExcel`. And you don't even need an installed Excel.   ;-)

Comment: How can i start loop for( $row = $data.GetLowerBound(0); $row -lt $data.GetUpperBound(0); $row++) from second row ? why $report[$vmname] = @{} failing as i mentioned above ?