# updating hash table while reading excel file failing in powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, hashtable

Any idea why below code is failing.

```
# Open an Excel workbook first:
$ExcelObj = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$ExcelWorkBook = $ExcelObj.Workbooks.Open("c:\anil\test.xlsx",2,$true)
$ExcelWorkSheet = $ExcelWorkBook.Sheets.Item("Sheet1")
# Get the number of filled in rows in the XLSX worksheet
$rowcount=$ExcelWorkSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
$report = @{}
$outFile = "vm_info.csv"
"VM Name,Vcenter,Disk usage" | Out-File -FilePath $outFile
######
$data = $ExcelWorksheet.Range("A1:Z100000").Value2
for( $row = 2 ; $row -lt $data.GetUpperBound(0); $row++) { 
                         $vmname = $data[$row, 1]
                         if ( $vmname -notin $report.keys){
                         $report[$vmname] = @{}
                        $report[$vmname]['vcenter'] = $data[$row, 5]
                        $report[$vmname]['datasize'] = $data[$row, 12]
                                                           }
                         }

$ExcelWorkBook.close($true) 
        $report.GetEnumerator()|foreach {

        "$($_.name),$($_.value.vcenter),$($_.value.datasize)" | Out-File -FilePath $outFile -Append
                                        }
```

## Message getting

Index operation failed; the array index evaluated to null.
At C:\anil\scripts\get_vm_disk_usage_from_excel.ps1:20 char:26

- ```
                       $report[$vmname] = @{}
  ```
- ```
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArrayIndex

Comment: Isn't that stil lthe same question like this: [Speed up reading excel file using PowerShell in hash table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74955460/speed-up-reading-excel-file-using-powershell-in-hash-table)?

Comment: The error indicates that `$vmname` has been assigned `$null` at the time of the call. Maybe add an `if($null -eq $vmname){ continue }` statement when you first enter the `for` loop

Comment: i do see $vmname has value. But assigning to Hash table $report[$vmname] = @{} , having issue. any idea ?